# Issue with login script

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I'm trying to make a login script but I'm stick with a problem:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT id
         FROM users
         WHERE username = '$username'
         AND password = '$password'"
    );

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        header('Location: ?error');
        exit();
    }

    // assign id to session
    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($query, 0, 'id');
    mysql_query(
        "UPDATE users
         SET last_activity = ".time()."
         WHERE ".$_SESSION['id']
    );

    header("Location: /");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The problem with this script is that it sets last_activity to current time on EVERY user.
Can't figure the problem out.

Some help would be greatly appricated, and yes I'm gonna look into password encrypting later :P

**edit: found problem, should be `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = ".time()." WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']);`**

Comment: Robert, put your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql function now() as opposed to the php function time() - not that it makes a huge difference but its slightly neater as you don't have to break the string to do it. E.g. "Update tablename set time=now() where condition"